# How to configure static routing between two layer 3 switches?

Tags: routing, switch, vlan, layer3

I have two Cisco **layer 3** switches. In switch 1, I created two vlans, 10.10.1.0/24 and 10.10.2.0/24. The connection is shown in the figure.

- PC 1 and PC 2 have static IP address (10.10.1.5 and 10.10.2.5)
- switch 2 is connected to switch 1 through vlan 2
- DHCP pool is **not** activated in both switch 1 and 2

To let PC 1 and PC 2 communicate with each other (for example, use ping to verify), I should configure **static route** in switches, right? How to configure this?

[image]

Comment: Looking at your setup, you don't need any static routing as PC2 is on a network which has it's default gateway on Switch 1.  As both networks are terminated on Switch1, Switch 1 knows about both networks, so can route between them.  You just need to ensure the default gateway for PC1 is 10.10.1.1 and for PC2, 10.10.2.1.  Ensure VLAN 2 is trunked to Switch 2 and PC2 switchport is an access port on VLAN 2.  Make sure PC2 can ping its default geteway, then you should be OK

Comment: yes, it works..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your setup, you don't need any static routing as PC2 is on a network which has it's default gateway on Switch 1. As both networks are terminated on Switch1, Switch 1 knows about both networks, so can route between them. You just need to ensure the default gateway for PC1 is 10.10.1.1 and for PC2, 10.10.2.1. Ensure VLAN 2 is trunked to Switch 2 and PC2 switchport is an access port on VLAN 2. Make sure PC2 can ping its default geteway, then you should be OK

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you Karl, and if you allow me, I would like to mention that in some switches (i.e Cisco) you need to activate the layer 3 capability. Otherwise, you will be able to create all the VLAN interfaces, but they won't be able to talk to each other.

Comment: u mean enable "ip routing"? Switch(configure) # ip routing, like this?

Comment: Exactly! This command is not activated by default on Cisco switches.

Answer (score 0):

To let PC 1 and PC 2 communicate with each other .

In Switch1 layer3 device :
.

Just creating a vlans is not enough . Configure switch virtual interface (SVI) on layer3 switch
.

`Switch1(config)#int Vlan 1`

`Switch(config)#ip address  10.10.1.1 255.255.255.0`

`Switch1 (config)# no shutdown`

`Switch1(config)#int Vlan2`

`Switch(config)#ip address 10.10.2.1 255.255.255.0`

`Switch1 (config)#no shutdown`

`Switch1(config)# ip routing`

Now connect pc 1 to switch1 and try to ping 10.10.1.5 from layer3 switch 1 . It will ping.

Further connect switch2 with Switch1 and Configure link with trunk allowing all Vlans .

Now in switch2 connect PC2 and configure access-port passing Vlan 2 . Try to ping 10.10.2.5 from layer3 switch 1 it will ping & PC1 and PC2 also pings each other .